# 12 firms and a total of 204 observations, can I use pooled OLS with firm-dummies or should I use fixed factor?

Tags: categorical-data, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, unbalanced-classes

I am studying the effect of government ownership on firm performance, more specifically I am studying the effect of the government reducing their share in companies which are already partly privatized.

I have collected relevant data for 12 firms where the state have reduced (or increased in some firms) their share since 1990. For a limited number of firms I have data from 1990, but for most of the firms the data starts in the 90`s (all firms have observations until 2013). So the data is unbalanced with a total of 204 observations.

[image: Some of the dataset]

I want to estimate the effect of "STATE SHARE" on "ROS" where "INDEX" and "YEAR" will be control variables.

My initial thoughts were to create dummies for every firm so that differences in the firm-averages would not influence my results. After trying to google the issue I have started to wonder if I should do a fixed-effects analyses, but I am struggling to understand the difference between just adding firm-dummies and doing a fixed effects regression where the firms are the fixed factors.

How can I best study the effect of reduced government ownership with the dataset I have collected? All help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you called "pooled OLS with firm dummies" is essentially fixed effects. Subtracting firm means from your variables for each firm (the so-called within transformation) that is done by computing the fixed effects estimator is the same as including dummies for your firms. A similar question has been asked here before so this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117159/is-subtracting-individual-means-in-pre-processing-an-appropriate-alternative-to/117165#117165) will provide the technical details and the reference you need.

If you want to know whether you should run pooled OLS (without firm dummies) or a fixed (or random) effects regression you can use the [Hausman test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/hausman/info) to make a decision. In most economic applications of panel data it is very likely that some of your observed control variables are correlated with the firm fixed effect. For instance, the number of exports/sales is likely to be correlated with the location of the firm (which usually doesn't change over time).

Another issue is: why did the government reduce their share in those firms? They might have just gotten rid of the bad firms that were already declining. In that case it will look as if reduced government ownership will make firms worse off. Fixed effects will not deal with such selection problems unless the reasons for the selection are fixed over time - and typically they are not. The econometric solution for this would be [instrumental variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/instrumental-variables/info) but generally it is not easy to find a good instrument.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Do you know how to perform a Hausmann test in SPSS? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I haven't heard of a ready canned package for it in SPSS but it can easily be done by hand as suggested in this answer in the Statalist: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-01/msg00059.html

Comment: We have now switched from SPSS to STATA, where we are grouping and clustering the panel data by FIRMID, which is has a unique number for each company. The commands we are currently using are as follows:
xtset FIRMID
xtreg DEP_VAR IND_VAR1 IND_VAR2, fe cluster(FIRMID)
With 12 firms and an average of 17 time periods per firm, total n of 206. Is this a good way to go? What we are mainly worried about now is heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation, which it seems the cluster command should be robust for with a large enough N. How large would N need to be for this to be the case?

Comment: Yes, the clustering takes care for heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation. How large is "large" cannot really be answered and even if, the sample size is what it is. I don't think you can really change that.

Comment: I hope it is ok that I ask another question regarding the same regression. If I, in addition to one control variable, add
three explainable variables (stateshare and stateshare lagged one year and another lagged two years) is there anything
preventing me from testing wether the three stateshare variables are jointly significant? The reason I ask is that someone told me that it is impossible to do an F-test with three or more variables in my regression.

Comment: @OleOlsen what nonsense.. of course the F-test can be used with more than three variables. In fact, Stata reports an F-test of the whole model versus an intercept only model every time you use the regress command. What was said to you is just not true.