# Fixed Effects Intuition: mean subtraction; categorical variables; and more

Tags: categorical-data, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

After read [this](https://theeffectbook.net/ch-FixedEffects.html) textbook chapter on fixed effects panel regression by Nick Huntington-Klein, a few questions remain:

1. Is fixed effects regression essentially OLS after normalising the data by subtracting the mean of each individual?

For clarity, this data:

| Individual | Year | Exercise (hours/week) | Cholesterol (y-variable) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | 2020 | 20 | 200 |
| Sarah | 2021 | 25 | 190 |
| Robert | 2020 | 50 | 230 |
| Robert | 2021 | 60 | 225 |

after normalisation, would be:

| Individual | Year | Exercise (hours/week) | Cholesterol (y-variable) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | 2020 | -2.5 | 5 |
| Sarah | 2021 | 2.5 | -5 |
| Robert | 2020 | -5 | 2.5 |
| Robert | 2021 | 5 | -2.5 |

This ensures the between differences are cancelled out and what remains is only within differences... If my understanding it correct, is that essentially what the R `plm` and Python `PanelOLS` (specifying "within") functions are doing before fitting OLS? Could one simply do the normalisation step separately and then use R's `lm` or Python's statsmodels `OLS`?

2. I have [read](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117165/134691) that mean subtraction is equivalent to including individual dummies. If I choose to go the mean-subtraction route, and I have a categorical variable in my data, e.g. favourite food: "Pizza"/"Pasta"/"Salad", how should that be dealt with and normalised? Surely I would need to create dummies, so I'm not sure how there can be a choice...
3. If I add a binary independent variable for each individual, e.g.:

| Individual | Year | Exercise (hours/week) | Was Employed | Cholesterol (y-variable) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | 2020 | 20 | 0 | 200 |
| Sarah | 2021 | 25 | 1 | 190 |
| Robert | 2020 | 50 | 0 | 230 |
| Robert | 2021 | 60 | 0 | 225 |

Should this variable be processed/normalised as if it were continuous (i.e., no special treatment)?

4. Can variables that are constant through time for each individual (e.g., Country of birth) provide any useful information for the model, or can they be disregarded since they provide no *within* information to explain cholesterol?
5. After normalisation, it seems one typically uses OLS (and this is what is built into `plm` and `PanelOLS`). But could any regression be used? E.g. Random Forest Regression, Ridge/LASSO, Support Vector Regression, etc
6. If the research question is "does employment influence cholesterol?", then does having Robert in the model provide any information, since he was never employed?

Comment: The normalized data table is incorrect. Only categorical variables (year) should cancel out. If (like in this table) you only have 4 rows with 4 distinct values for a numerical variable (which is not naturally categorical, like exercise hours & cholesterol), it may be standardized using $x'_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}-\bar{x}_j}{\sqrt{Cov(x_j)}}$ but there's no cancellation there. That being said, you might consider relating exercise/cholesterol as fixed effects if they have a discrete set of values, with a small number of repeating values.

Comment: Thanks, good point about the standardisation. I'll use `z = (x - u) / s` in that case.  Could you please elaborate on your last sentence

Comment: There's a point in discretizing a continuous variable only if it behaves like a categorical one: has very few unique values over the whole set of samples. How few? My rule of thumb is 4, but it depends on the number of samples.

Comment: noted. So if they are considered categorical as per your definition (which in my example they are not), then I treat them differently, e.g. create dummy variables out of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you liked the chapter! To answer your questions:

1. Correct. In a linear model, fixed effects regression is just OLS performed after subtracting out the individual-level means of each variable (the "de-meaning" approach). I wouldn't call this "normalization," which implies both subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. You're only subtracting the mean.
2. If you have a categorical variable, you would turn it into a set of binary indicators (as you might normally do in linear regression) and subtract out the means of those. So in your table in question 3, Was Employed would be `(-.5, .5, 0 ,0)`.
3. Same as above.
4. Variables that are constant over time within individual provide no useful information if included directly; they are collinear with the fixed effect themselves, and there is no variation in them after accounting for fixed effects (and thus nothing to study). That said, there's not really a *need* to control for these variables anyway, as the fixed effect itself accounts for it. Assuming no individuals change gender over time, a fixed effect for individual accounts for any effect of gender. Random-effects models can incorporate information about these variables into the individual-level effect and improve precision, but fixed effects does not. Sometimes in fixed effects models you will see fixed-over-time covariates included as part of interaction terms with variables that do change over time - that's fine.
5. Unfortunately, while the *logic* of fixed effects extends to all sorts of models, the methods for estimation do not, and you can't just assume that your approach to estimating fixed effects with OLS extends to other models. For nonlinear models like logit I can tell you they don't outside of a few very simple cases, and you need specialized estimators. See the [nonlinear models section](https://theeffectbook.net/ch-FixedEffects.html#fixed-effects-in-nonlinear-models) of the fixed effects chapter. As for those machine learning models I'm not sure! But you can't just assume it will work. In some cases it's obvious it won't - for regularized regression or random forest, for example, you'd clearly get a different result whether you de-mean the data (which forces all data to be just the within variation) vs. including the fixed effects as penalizable/selectable parameters (for which some individuals will see their individual effect dropped or reduced). Which one of those is the "right" way, if either? I don't know. Might depend on whether you're including the FEs to improve prediction vs. identify a causal effect. I'd recommend looking up literature on applying within-variation methods for those estimators in particular.
6. Having Robert in the model can improve the predictive power of the model and the estimation of covariate coefficients and thus help with precision, but he will not contribute to the effect-size estimate. See Question 3 in [this section](https://theeffectbook.net/ch-FixedEffects.html#regression-estimators) of the chapter. The treatment effect average that fixed effects gives you puts a weight on each individual's effect size that's based on their residual variance of the effect. If they have no effect variance after you limit things to within variation they'll get a weight of 0.